# Implement smooth text transition in React Native

Tags: react-native

I try to implement component that takes takes text property and depend on previous value shows smooth transition:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { Animated, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const usePrevious = (value) => {
    const ref = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value
    }, [value])

    return ref.current
}

export default function AnimatedText({ style, children }) {

    const fadeInValue = new Animated.Value(0)

    const fadeOutValue = new Animated.Value(1)

    const prevChildren = usePrevious(children)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (children != prevChildren) {
            animate()
        }
    }, [children])

    const animate = () => {
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(fadeInValue, {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 1000,
                useNativeDriver: true
            }),
            Animated.timing(fadeOutValue, {
                toValue: 0,
                duration: 1000,
                useNativeDriver: true
            })
        ]).start()
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Animated.Text style={[ style, { opacity: fadeInValue }]}>{children}</Animated.Text>
            {
                prevChildren &&
                <Animated.Text style={[ style, styles.animatedText, { opacity: fadeOutValue }]}>{prevChildren}</Animated.Text>
            }
        </>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    animatedText: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
    }
})
```

As the result I got smooth transition between component rendering with different children arguments. But there is a flickering due to some reasons related to animated value updates. Is there any way to avoid this problem or better solution to implement such component?

Comment: I put a working example into Expo Snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@ridvanaltun/frisky-apple, it is not an answer btw, I'm just helping out to test things easy

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution with `react-native-reanimated`. It's not elegant implementation but it seems to work correctly without flickering:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

import Animated, { useSharedValue, useAnimatedStyle, withTiming } from 'react-native-reanimated'

const usePrevious = (value) => {
    const ref = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value
    }, [value])

    return ref.current
}

export default function AnimatedText({ style, children }) {

    const fadeValue1 = useSharedValue(0)

    const fadeValue2 = useSharedValue(1)

    const toggleFlagRef = useRef(false)

    const animatedTextStyle1 = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
            opacity: withTiming(fadeValue1.value, { duration: 1000 })
        }
    })

    const animatedTextStyle2 = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
            opacity: withTiming(fadeValue2.value, { duration: 1000 })
        }
    })

    const prevChildren = usePrevious(children)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (children != prevChildren) {
            animate()
        }
    }, [children])

    const animate = () => {
        if (toggleFlagRef.current) {
            fadeValue1.value = 0
            fadeValue2.value = 1
        } else {
            fadeValue1.value = 1
            fadeValue2.value = 0
        }

        toggleFlagRef.current = !toggleFlagRef.current
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Animated.Text style={[ style, animatedTextStyle1 ]}>{toggleFlagRef.current ? prevChildren : children}</Animated.Text>
            {
                prevChildren &&
                <Animated.Text style={[ style, styles.animatedText, animatedTextStyle2 ]}>{toggleFlagRef.current ? children : prevChildren}</Animated.Text>
            }
        </>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    animatedText: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
    }
})
```